# CP not loading on Forge Server with PHP 7

Tags: control-panel, config, php, error

I uploaded a working install of `Craft Pro 2.5.2754` to a brand new Laravel Forge server and I'm having issues with the control panel. More precisely, it returns an error 500 when I try to access it.

The PHP version is `PHP 7.0.0-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1` and it's the default config of Forge.

I have a config array in craft/config/general.php that looks like this :

```
$data['dev.domain.com']  =   [
    'appId'                 => 'choiStage',
    //'cacheMethod'           => 'memcache',
    'devMode'               => true,
    'phpMaxMemoryLimit'     => '512M',
    'cpTrigger'             => 'craft',

    'backupDbOnUpdate'      => true,
    'usePathInfo'           => true,
    'omitScriptNameInUrls'  => true,
    'enableCsrfProtection'  => false,
];
return $data;
```

When I access the control panel located at /craft I get an error 500.

When I have a look at craft/storage/runtime/log/craft.log there is this message :

```
    ******************************************************************************************************
2015/12/09 15:42:38 [error] [exception.Error] Error: Class 'Twig_Cache_Filesystem' not found in /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:263
Stack trace:
#0 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(115): Twig_Environment->setCache('/home/forge/cho...')
#1 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(147): Twig_Environment->__construct(Object(Craft\TemplateLoader), Array)
#2 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/services/TemplatesService.php(221): Craft\TemplatesService->getTwig()
#3 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/controllers/BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render('login', Array)
#4 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/controllers/TemplatesController.php(55): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate('login', Array)
#5 [internal function]: Craft\TemplatesController->actionRender('login', Array)
#6 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CAction.php(109): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Craft\TemplatesController), Array)
#7 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(Object(Craft\TemplatesController), Object(ReflectionMethod), Array)
#8 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#9 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#10 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#11 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('render')
#12 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('templates/rende...')
#13 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(284): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#14 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#15 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#16 /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/public/index.php(19): require_once('/home/forge/cho...')
#17 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/craft/login
---
```

I tried various cacheMethod without any luck and now I'm kinda stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2015/12/09 15:42:38 [error] [exception.Error] Error: Class 'Twig_Cache_Filesystem' not found in /home/forge/staging.domain.com/releases/20151209154140/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php:263
```

That indicates that Craft is missing some of its files.  Try re-uploading your `craft/app` folder with a fresh copy downloaded from https://craftcms.com.